How do I fetch a list of users from my Firebase Realtime Database when each users data is stored under a unique 16 digit key on Xcode using UIKit?
I've already built the same exact app for android using android studio so I don't want to make any changes to the database whatsoever.
If the solution to fetching users from Firebase and displaying them in a TableView includes changing the structure of the Realtime Database, then I would not prefer implementing it.
Given below is a screenshot of my Firebase Realtime Database:

import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class NewConversationsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let TtableView: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView()
        table.isHidden = false
        table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return table
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
        let usersRef = databaseRef.child("user")

        usersRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let userSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot
                let userDict = userSnapshot.value as? [String: Any]
                let userKey = userSnapshot.key
                let username = userDict?["userName"] as? String
                let grade = userDict?["grade"] as? String
                let profilepic = userDict?["profilepic"] as? String
                // Continue to extract other data as needed
                
                print("User Data: \(username)\(grade)")
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print("Error fetching user data: \(error)")
        }
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel",
                                                            style: .done,
                                                            target: self,
                                                            action: #selector(dismissSelf))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .systemBlue
    }
    
    @objc private func dismissSelf() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

The code above prints the users grades and names perfectly, I just need help with displaying them in the TableView


There are lots of examples available for UITableView.  Have you tried to implement the required delegate methods? In your completion handler you need to assign the fetched documents to an array property and reload the tableview.

Use this function replace with your path.
Observe value by .childAdded / .childChanged

.childAdded

func observeUsers(completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?, _ data: [String: Any]?) -> Void) {
ref.child("path/to/ids").observe(.childAdded, with: {
(snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
    
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    
    let url = value?["url"] as? String
    
    let data = [
        "url": url
    ] as? [String: Any]
    
    completion(nil, msg)
}) { (error) in
    completion(error, nil)
}

}

.childChanged

func observeUsers(completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?, _ data: [String: Any]?) -> Void) {
ref.child("path/to/ids").observe(.childAdded, with: {
(snapshot) in
print(snapshot)
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    
    let url = value?["url"] as? String
    
    let data = [
        "url": url
    ] as? [String: Any]
    
    completion(nil, msg)
}) { (error) in
    completion(error, nil)
}

}
